# Google PageSpeed Score Calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-pagespeed

I am trying to include the `Google PageSpeed Insights` Score in my application. I came across the api for it and have tried to use it:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://wikipedia.org&filter_third_party_resources=true&locale=en_US&screenshot=false&strategy=desktop&key=MyAPIKey
```

After this I got the output as shown in the gist:
https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/6f8c5661e11654f301247edca45d23df

But when I use the application of PageSpeed Insights, with same domain as : `WikiPedia.org`, I got different result of score and could not find that in the JSON api: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwikipedia.org&tab=mobile

I am using Python2.7 with windows10. and have tried this code for accessing the api:

```
>>> url = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://wikipedia.org&filter_third_party_resources=true&locale=en_US&screenshot=false&strategy=desktop&key=MYAPIKey"
>>> response = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> data = json.loads(response.read())
print data.
```

But I want to have the exact scoring as shown on the PageSpeedInsights of Google. Kindly suggest me what is the way to have the same score as that of Google Insights Page. I could not see the same score in the API result anyways.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? The page score (87) is correct in your json.

Comment: Sure Let me tell you. The output what you see right now is same. But for different URL I get different results and the Desktop result is given and not the Mobile. How do I calculate the accuracy.

Comment: What does the accuracy mean?

Comment: Sure take this example: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/ec906ef242f61104ffb04b687bf1a3f7 I have attached the screen shots of the scores from the PageSpeed and the response generated by the API.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see a reference to accuracy. Could you perhaps give me a word or two to directly search?

Comment: See, What I mean with the accuracy is how to get the score of Mobile and Desktop exactly the same as shown on the PageSpeed Insights page. The scoring is distorted most of the times. As you can see in the image and the response that is generated, the figure are totally different. And How to I know that the score genrated is of the Mobile or Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

For Desktop/Mobile: set `strategy=desktop` to `strategy=mobile` in the url.

Discrepancies between the JSON and the website could possibly just be variation within multiple runs, since it's likely the website doesn't fall squarely within scoring buckets. However, it seems that the score is relatively stable within a 1-score range for both desktop and mobile.

Comment: Well, what If I need to have both score in single json with single click on the API? Also, I don't think that the scoring is stable enough. Are you a Google Guy? So may be you know the API better. If you are a programmer then you might not have used the API till now, hence didn't came across the problem I am facing. But still you answer is a good attempt. Thank you